# If all the charges of a system are in X-Y plane, is it necessary that the center of charge be in X-Y plane?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electric-fields

In this case, since the z-coordinate is zero, $\sum_{i} q_i z_i = 0$. This was the answer I found when I googled it it. But I have a doubt about it. Every charge has an electric field around it, does this electric field come into z axis and play a role in centre of charge in Z plane? I know that this question is weird but I need to clarify this doubt. That's why I asked. Can anyone please answer this question?

Comment: Why do you think that the electric fields due to the individual charges contribute to the centre of "charge"?

Comment: Individual charges have electric field. Eg:when we think some positive charges are placed at the corners of a square, so the electric field will be max. at the centre due to all the charges,thus it may  be the centre of cahrges

Answer (score 0):

If all the charges are on the x-y plane, then the resulting field will also be symmetric about the x-y plane.  Because the field equipotential lines around any 1 charge have the same magnitude for any +z position as they do for the corresponding -z position (x,y constant).

I don't know the term "center of charge" in this context.  The total field is a summation of the [contribution](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Calculus-Based_Physics_(Schnick)/Volume_B%3A_Electricity_Magnetism_and_Optics/B03%3A_The_Electric_Field_Due_to_one_or_more_Point_Charges#:%7E:text=other%20or%20themselves.-,Superposition,due%20to%20each%20source%20charge.) of all the charges.  [Here is a page](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/18-5-electric-field-lines-multiple-charges/) with interactive simulation on this.